# How can we predict if a news 'article' is 'fake'?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I am testing the sample code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

#Read the data
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\news.csv')
#Get shape and head
df.shape
df.tail()

#DataFlair - Get the labels
labels=df.label
labels.head()


#DataFlair - Split the dataset
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df['text'], labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)


#DataFlair - Initialize a TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_df=0.7)
#DataFlair - Fit and transform train set, transform test set
tfidf_train=tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train) 
tfidf_test=tfidf_vectorizer.transform(x_test)


#DataFlair - Initialize a PassiveAggressiveClassifier
pac=PassiveAggressiveClassifier(max_iter=50)
pac.fit(tfidf_train,y_train)
#DataFlair - Predict on the test set and calculate accuracy
y_pred=pac.predict(tfidf_test)
score=accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
print(f'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)}%')


#DataFlair - Build confusion matrix
confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred, labels=['FAKE','REAL'])
```

Result:

```
array([[589,  49],
       [ 45, 584]], dtype=int64)
```

Now, if I want to predict if a string of text is fake, how would I do that?

I put this small code sample together.

```
#  non-numeric format
a = ['this is fake'] 
#  convert using numpy
b = np.array(a, dtype=float) 
print(pac.predict([[b]]))
```

That gives me this error.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'this is fake'
```

How can I predict of a string is 'fake'? Thanks.

Source Info.

https://data-flair.training/blogs/advanced-python-project-detecting-fake-news/

Source Data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1er9NJTLUA3qnRuyhfzuN0XUsoIC4a-_q/view

Comment: You need to apply the same preprocessing steps (e.g. tokenizing and vectorizing) that you applied to your training data before feeding it to your model.

Comment: Just updated the code sample. So, how do I don that? This is the key, right: y_pred=pac.predict(tfidf_test)

Can you also make up a string, or a series of strings, and predict if this is fake?

Comment: I found a solution here!
https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2021/06/30/fake-news-detection-with-machine-learning/